# Does a later proxy_set_header override an earlier one in the same location block?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I can't find any documentation that explicitly states whether subsequent nginx `proxy_set_header` directives will override earlier ones in the same block or not.

As you can see below I have 3 `proxy_set_header Connection some_value` directives in a single location block (because there is 1 in each of the included snippet files, and one after to override those).

I thought this was working, but I've recently seen some errors which suggest it isn't (not really relevant to the question).

Here is the nginx location block (and preceding definition of `$connection_upgrade`) in my configuration:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade
{
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}
```

```
location ~ /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket$
{
    proxy_pass http://mattermost_upstream;
    include snippets/proxy_websocket_params.conf;
    include snippets/proxy_params.conf;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    client_max_body_size 50M;
    proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    proxy_buffers 256 16k;
    proxy_buffer_size 16k;
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
}
```

`snippets/proxy_websocket_params.conf`:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

`snippets/proxy_params.conf`:

```
proxy_redirect     off;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
proxy_set_header   Host               $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy      true;
proxy_set_header   Connection         "";
```

Comment: Assuming you have `$connection_upgrade` defined somewhere, it seems to work as you suggest. The header value is silently overwritten by the last statement encountered.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, seems like confirmation that if there is a problem in my config it isn't that. That's helpful